# is it possible to render a XAML canvas wihtout Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is it possible to create an online photo editor in XAML (editor allows users to add text, other images, clipart) that simply renders in a browser without the need for the user to download a plug in like Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

No. Closest would be using HTML5's canvas and javascript and/or jquery.